# Android: Group elements (TextView) so they have share one onClick

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, onclicklistener

I'm making a sudoku app, and I have created a TableLayout with 81 individual TextView's to represent each square.

Now the problem is, I would like the user to be able to select a single square, then select a number to be put into the square they selected.
Is there any way I can group them together, then get the individual TextView they clicked?

Maybe something like this:

```
TextView selected;
table.setOnClickListener(new TableLayout.OnClickListener() {
    ***selected = (TextView) table.getSelectedElement() ?***
}
```

That way, when they choose a number I could just:

```
number.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    selected.setText( number.getText().toString() );
}
```

This way, I wouldn't have to make 81 separate onClick methods for each square, which I'm sure won't be the solution.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You wan to be able to click a square then change the text within it?

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you are using rows you can try something like:

```
int count = table.getChildCount();
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){ 
    final View row = table.getChildAt(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < row.getChildCount()){
        TextView textView = (TextView) row.getChildAt(j); 
        textView.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick (View v) {
                    //write some custom alert box that allows use to enter
                    //text. positive alert button should do the follow
                    v.setText(theResult);    
                }
            }
    }
}
```

you can optimize the code...I've wrote it straight into stackoverflow so sorry if I have errors.

Also cosider using `GridView`

Answer (score 0):

You can set an `onClickListener` to any View by adding `android:onClick="onClick"` attribute in your xml. In that case the parenting activity must have a function

```
public void onClick(View v) {
}
```

that will be called. The parameter `View v` is refference to the view that was clicked.

As @royB mentioned, you would save a lot of work if you implemented the table with a `GridView`.

Comment: I know how you can add an onClick method. The problem is, I have 81 View's and don't want to add a method for all 81.

Comment: I understand that. Why didn't you use the GridView?

Comment: That won't solve my problem. It may help to make the task of making the squares easier, but can it allow me to get which individual row and column was selected?

Comment: I am pretty sure it can

Comment: built a very simple app with gridview. You can set `onItemClickListener` and you will get the position of the element clicked.

Comment: I'll read into the documentation and see how it works and fits in my program. Thanks for the suggestion.